# Intermediate value in new created prototype

Tags: javascript, function, prototypejs

I've faced a problem which I can't understand. So I created a new function that contains a couple of functions. This is my code:

```
(() => {
    function BetterArray(array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    BetterArray.prototype.map = function (fn) {
        return Array.prototype.map.call(this.array, fn);
    };

    BetterArray.prototype.collect = function (fn) {
        return Array.prototype.map.call(this.array, fn);
    };

    const a = new BetterArray([1])
        .map((item) => item * 2)
        .collect((item) => item * 2);

    console.log(a);
})();
```

In line "collect" I got an error *Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).map(...).collect is not a function*. I'm just curious why this error is appearing and how can I write this code properly to avoid that. Additional thing is that when I change *map* with *collect* - I do not receive this error.

I know that both functions are the same, but I want to be sure that it's not based on the function body.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Does `BetterArray.prototype.map` return an instance of a `BetterArray` or an `Array`?

Comment: I'm not sure, I tried to see `Object.getPrototypeOf(a)` and seems that this is Array.prototype... So how can I 'stay' with my old prototype when im using 'call' fn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, the `.map` and `.collect` methods are returning *plain arrays*, and plain arrays don't have a `.collect` method on them.

When you call `.map` on a `BetterArray`, you should create and return a new instance of a `BetterArray` if you want to be able to call `BetterArray` methods like `.collect` on it afterwards:

```js
(() => {
    function BetterArray(array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    BetterArray.prototype.map = function (fn) {
        const arr = Array.prototype.map.call(this.array, fn);
        const newBetterArr = new BetterArray(arr);
        return newBetterArr;
    };

    BetterArray.prototype.collect = function (fn) {
        return Array.prototype.map.call(this.array, fn);
    };

    const a = new BetterArray([1])
        .map((item) => item * 2)
        .collect((item) => item * 2);

    console.log(a);
})();
```

(if you want `.collect` to result in a `BetterArray` instance as well, apply the same logic for the `.collect` method)

Comment: Okay got it now.. So now if I want to call other methods from other prototypes, and if these methods are returning plain objects like strings - then I should a return new instance of my prototype?

Comment: Right, if you want chained calls to result in the same sort of object, return a new instance at the end of the method.